# Check if the funds are locked for LockableCurrency

Tags: substrate-node-template, lockable-currency

I'm using `fn set_lock` inside `LockableCurrency` trait. It's possible to extend or remove lock, but no way to check if funds are in fact locked. Is this by design? and if so what is a good way to check that funds are locked for a given user?

Here is a short code snippet:

```
...
// how do I make sure `who` does not have any funds locked without tracking it inside my code?
ensure!(T::Currency::free_balance(&who) >= amount, "Not enough funds to do X");
T::Currency::set_lock(SOME_LOCK_ID, &who, amount, WithdrawReasons::all());
...
```

Answer (score 1):

IMO, there isn't an elegant way to do this.

I used `ensure_can_withdraw` in my code.

You can write:

```rs
// Why do I say this isn't elegant?
// Because you have to calculate the `new_balance` yourself here.
if T::Currency::ensure_can_withdraw(who, amount, reason, new_balance) {
  T::Currency::set_lock(amount);
} else {
  Err("Not enough funds to do X".into())?;
}
```